# What are the exact steps that are happening until a value transaction is completed

Tags: asktheexperts

Could you describe how exactly are (value) messages now executed in the new network? So from issuing from one address until arriving in a new address?
As a lot of things will change in the new network i would like to get an updated understanding of how the process works now.